# Looking for a Formula or VBA that can take an entered Name and return all Worksheets that name appears in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

What I would like it to be able to enter a name, then have Excel output each worksheet the name appears in. Each worksheet is an Application, with a list of users. I need to be able to search for a user, and have it return all Applications that user has access to.

I tried Googling it, and found a formula, but it wasn't what I was looking for. I'm not experienced enough to know how to come up with something that would do what I want, but am experienced enough to understand something written. Formula or VBA would work.

Comment: You can use Find All for this, no formula or VBA needed.  Is there a specific reason that Find All isn't working for you?

Comment: Will the names be anywhere in the sheets or in a specific location (cells, column, etc...)?

Comment: @tigeravatar how would I get that to output though?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The names will always be in Column A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Sub LookForName()
    Dim n As String, s As Worksheet, r As Range, msg As String

    n = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Name: ", Type:=2)
    msg = ""

    For Each s In Sheets
        Set r = s.Cells.Find(What:=n, After:=s.Cells(1, 1))
        If r Is Nothing Then
        Else
             msg = msg & vbCrLf & s.Name
        End If
    Next s
    If msg = "" Then msg = "Name not found."
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, that does it. this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much! wow.